# How does Java store +-Infinite in memory?

Tags: java, math, memory, infinite

If it takes all 32 bits to store from -2^31 to 2^31, how can it store + and - Infinite? Does it use more memory? Is it good and safe to store those values?

UPDATE: Thanks to the answers, I know that only floating point data types can store Inf value, Integers can't.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-2008

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams: What about Integer? This is what I mainly need to know.

Comment: Integers can't store infinities.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Java, along with most other programming languages, follows the [IEEE 754](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-2008) specification for *floating point numbers*. The range of the possible values is slightly reduced to allow for [the infinities as well as `NaN` (Not a Number)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Special_values). These are safe to store; they're even available as constants, for example [`Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#POSITIVE_INFINITY).

> If it takes all 32 byte to store from -2^31 to 2^31

I think you mean 32 *bits*, to store all of the possible integer values in this range. Java's Integer type works as you describe, and has no way to store infinities or other special values.

Comment: The link you provided for Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY is now invalid.

Answer (score 6):

> If it takes all 32 <s>byte</s> bits to store from -2^31 to 2^31...

There you're talking about [`Integer`s](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html).

> ...how can it store + and - Infinite?

There you're talking about [`Float`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html) and [`Double`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html), which are different data types. `Float` is a 32-bit IEEE 754 number, and `Double` is a 64-bit IEEE 754 number. [IEEE 754](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) floating-point numbers have special values set aside for positive and negative infinity.

There is no special "infinity" value in Java's `Integer` class, you can store the full range of values.

Comment: Thank you. I updated my question. I though Integer could store Infinity too.

Comment: @W.N.: Nope, no infinity in `Integer`. If you want it, you'll have to set aside a value to treat as infinity within your application, which could be tricky, or define your own class that aggregates an `Integer` along with a flag indicating it holds "infinity".